# Increment a variable within a Foreach Loop and use it-SSIS

Tags: ssis, foreach

I have a package i am using the foreach loop to loop through the databases. I am passing a string and it loops though all the databases. Everything is perfect till here.

What i want to achieve is that for each databases it loops, it should increment a variable by 1. suppose if i have to loop through a total of 5 databases. And a package level variable(myvariable =24) is declared as 24. for each databases it loops it should increment the variable by 1.

For that i have created a script task inside the foreachloop container. ReadWriteVariables as myvariable. In the script editor. I have the following code

```
public void Main()
        {
     int varbl = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::myvariable"].Value.ToString());
     varbl++
       }
```

and then i am passing that incremented value to a storedprocedure. But its not incrementing. It is still taking the default value of 24. Any ideas how can i increment a variable in foreachloop container?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable `varbl`that you created only exists in the script context.

To increment the SSIS variable you need to do something like

```
public void Main()
{
    int varbl = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::myvariable"].Value.ToString());
    varbl++;
    Dts.Variables["User::myvariable"].Value = varbl;
}
```

or the variable `User::myvariable` will not be changed