# SSIS Variable with loop

Tags: soap, ssis, skip

I am trying to download from SOAP API. The supplier has set a limit to download 1000 records per select. I would like to set up "for loop" container to iterate all records in one file.

The Url expect two variables for data i.e Select and Skip. For this I have added two variables @select and @skip and create a web service task and set up the variable with @Select and @Skip.

this webservice task runs ok, but i am stuck on working out a logic to loop through and download all rows in one file.

for the first run the @skip should be 0 for the consecutive run @skip should be previous value of @skip+1000.

Can someone please help to achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: How are you stuck on "working out a logic", you've stated the logic in your question:  after each iteration, increment SKIP by 1000.   So what are you stuck on?   I don't understand your question.

Comment: hi, thanks for response. I am stuck on implementing this logic with for loop task and iterate the data set.

Comment: Why?   What have you got so far, and what part don't you know how to do?

Comment: hi, i am not sure how i can set up the initial value for @skip to be 0 and and add 1000 for each run.

Comment: You can perform both actions with script tasks.

Comment: Tab, I would be grateful if you could show me a sample. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increment a variable within a Foreach Loop and use it-SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221674/increment-a-variable-within-a-foreach-loop-and-use-it-ssis)