# Display foreach loop iteration number in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container, ssis-2017

I need to keep a check on the iteration number for a foreach loop container task that I am running in Visual Studio 2017. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: display where?  what are you specifically trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just need to keep track of the iteration number somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## (1) Count iterations using Expression Task

*Task available in SSIS 2012+*

In Foreach Loop container, [there is no properties that contains the iteration number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-2017). You can achieve this by creating a SSIS variable of type Int, with a initial value equal `0`. example `@[User::Counter]`

Inside the Foreach loop container, add an `Expression Task` with the following expression:

```
@[User::Counter] = @[User::Counter] + 1
```

**Helpful Links**

- [SSIS Expression Task](https://chrisalbrektson.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/ssis-expression-task/)
- [Expression Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/expression-task?view=sql-server-2017)

## (2) Count iterations using a Script Task

You can achieve the same process using a Script Task, by creating the counter variable, select it as ReadWrite Variable in the Script Task, and inside the script add a similar line into the Main Function:

```
Dts.Variables["User::Counter"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::Counter"].Value) + 1;
```

**References**

- [Increment a variable within a Foreach Loop and use it-SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221674/increment-a-variable-within-a-foreach-loop-and-use-it-ssis)
- [Use SSIS Variables and Parameters in a Script Task](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22194.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-task.aspx)

### Displaying data

There are different ways of displaying data. One is to use a script task. Specify your `@[User::Counter]` variable is in the ReadOnly collection and then emit the value into the run log

```
    public void Main()
    {
        bool fireAgain = false;
        string message = "{0}::{1} : {2}";
        foreach (var item in Dts.Variables)
        {
            Dts.Events.FireInformation(0, "SCR Echo Back", string.Format(message, item.Namespace, item.Name, item.Value), string.Empty, 0, ref fireAgain);
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

A different approach would be to set the `Name` property of a Task within the Foreach Loop via an expression.  Right-click on a Task within the Loop and select Properties. Find the `[+]Expressions` collection in the Properties section and click the right side ellipses `...` and in the new window, select Name in the left hand side and set the right-hand side expression to be

```
"My Task " + RIGHT("000" + (DT_WSTR,3) @[User::Counter], 3)
```

This concatenates two strings "My Task" and converts the Counter variable to a string and left pads it with zeroes so it's always a 3 digit number